# error: unable to read the file when I use xcodebuild -create-xcframework

Tags: swift, xcode, arm64, xcodebuild, xcframework

I use xcodebuild command line to generate framework

1.

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme ABCDE \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
-archivePath './build/ABCDE.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

2. 

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme ABCDE \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
-archivePath './build/ABCDE.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

2 Steps are success

but when I need to generate XCFramework

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework './build/ABCDE.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ABCDE.framework' \
-framework './build/ABCDE.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ABCDE.framework' \
-output './build/ABCDE.xcframework'
```

I got error message like this
**error: unable to read the file -> ABCDE.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ABCDE.framework/ABCDE**

Could anyone face the problem like this and how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Please include the full text of the error message, it's essential for finding a solution.

Comment: Fighting with same issue... on the test build I generated `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and make archive based on this project and scheme. I got the framework  binary in folder. But ... its all useless for me... I needs solution without xcodeproj.